# Avoid different representation of the same serializer. Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Imagine I have a model which looks like following:

```
class Author(models.Model):

    books = models.ManyToManyField()
```

and a serializer for Book objects:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.title
```

I am using it to represent Book objects for Author entities. I have two different serializers for GET and POST requests but the books field is absolutely the same.

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    books = BookSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('books', ...)
```

My problem is that one AuthorSerializer (GET requests) returns data correctly:

```
books = ['...', '...']
```

while the one for POST requests returns it with IDs.

```
books = [{'id': 1, 'title': '...'}]
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: is `book` in the Author model really singular, or is there an `s` missing?

Comment: @jkoestinger its just a mechanical mistake, fixed.

Comment: Can you share the view and serializers? What data do you return in post? Is it the request data or the serializer data?

Answer (score 0):

try adding below line to the BookSerializer Meta class.

```
exclude=('id',)
```

Comment: You can not use both fields and exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Book serializer is ambiguous, because it has a `to_representation` method AND a list of declared fields to be serialized, and these two contradict each other. Using a method instead might solve it:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    books = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_books(self, obj: Author):
        return obj.books.all().values_list('title', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('books', ...)
```

Comment: Using SerializerMethodField will of course solve it. I just wonder why the data of the same serializer is represented differently.